# 'str' object has no attribute 'columns' when I try to use the function "to.csv"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to use the funcion to.csv to export a dataset but the error "'str' object has no attribute 'columns'" was reported. That's my script:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('Documents/Pos/ETLSIM/Dados/ETLSIM.DORES_MG_2019_t.csv', low_memory="false")
data2 = pd.read_csv('Documents/Pos/ETLSIM/ETLSIM.DORES_MG_2018_t.csv', low_memory="false")
df_concat = pd.concat([data,data2], sort = False)
df_concat.to_csv('concatenado.csv')
```

Comment: How are your data structured in the csv files? Can you give an example?

Comment: Please post the entire traceback so we an see the fail. Also, Your code should generate a dataframe that demonstrates the the problem. You could use the first few lines of your csv for that.

Comment: You should post a sample of your dataframes.